# Django : View for submit?

Tags: django

It is a good way to create a view only for submit a form ?

For example :

Ajax send a form submitted to this specific view, this view validate the form and create a object in database and return a json response to Ajax.

It's ok to do like this ?

Because I'am afraid of users write directly the url to this specific view on browser...

Comment: Validate the submission via a CSRF token, and additionally by checking the authenticated user's permission to create the object.

Comment: In the view ? I didn't understand the "Validate the submission via a CSRF token"

Comment: If it can be accessed via ajax, uses can probe it manually as well. Your site won't last long if your security depends on users not looking at what the code is doing. Design a better system (one time use tokens?) should this actually be necessary.